# Is it OK to create the HTML first for an ASP.Net or ASP.Net MVC site?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

Does it work OK to code the HTML first for an ASP.Net or ASP.Net MVC site, and then hand this off to the coders?  If not, what would be the best approach to integrating these?

Comment: Did you post the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554658/how-to-best-integrate-html-design-with-c-code-in-asp-net-or-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Yes, it's a slightly different but similar question--I'd like to merge that one with this one, but not sure how to.

Answer (score 4):

This is absolutely acceptable. That is one of the great things about MVC.

Create your HTML and CSS and let the developers code in the dynamic bits and worry about all that side of it.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to hear, we're leaning towards MVC, would like to keep things lightweight and scalable.  Also seems like it could be easier to work with your designers in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's anything necessarily wrong with that approach.  I know places that have web designers mock-up html to give their developers "starting points" to creating their pages.

Comment: So is the developer the de-facto graphic design implementer?  I'm a bit leery of that (unless its an incredibly simple design).

Comment: In an ideal world, no.  Although, at a the majority of places I've worked that's been the case; the company doesn't want to pay for a web designer so they expect the developer to do it all.  Unfortunately, a lot of the web sites I've seen have reflected that decision.  As a developer, I like the idea of having a professional design the layout and style as it leaves me free to implement its functionality.

Answer (score 2):

It works quite well. Some of the HTML may be replaced with ASP controls.

Personally I'd rather start from a HTML page that's reasonably well mocked-up rather than a JPEG in a Word Doc.

Comment: Probably not ASP Controls given that it is an MVC application.

Answer (score 2):

For **ASP.NET MVC** yes this is certainly possible. In fact, that's one of the benefits of **MVC**. You can switch your front end at a whim without a big, breaking change. Web designers can work independently of back end developers.

With **WebForms** (Traditional **ASP.NET**) this is possible, but not so easy. With things like the code behind page being the main issue. Web designers shouldn't care about this, but **ASP.NET** has the code behind tied to the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about doing a mockup then it really depends on what you expect them to do with it in terms of dynamic content that will be added.  The html may not be useful to them at all, but it would probably be better than a mockup in anything else, since the html will limit you to doing things that are easily implemented in asp.net.  where as a mockup in word or photoshop would allow you to do things that might not be easily implemented in asp.net.  So I would say html mockup is a good idea.

If there is no programming to be done, i.e. it is just a static hmtl page, then I'd just link to it as an html page.

Comment: So for a non-static page are you saying the programmers should also implement the graphic design of the site?  Is this not a bit risky?

Comment: Where did I say the programmers should implement the graphic design of the page?  The designer doing the mockups in html can include graphics if they want.

Answer (score -3):

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Image(picture pic)
    {
        var path = "";

        foreach (var file in pic.Files)
        {

            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {


                var filename = file.FileName;


                path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images"), filename);



                file.SaveAs(path);


            }  

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```